# Sending JMS messages between 2 systems

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, messagebroker, message-listener

I have 2 systems where System A has to send messages to System B. I am new to JMS so I don't have a big idea on how to implement this. I was thinking of using a message broker (ActiveMQ) to send messages. So, System A will send messages to a queue and the Message Listener in B will consume those messages. There are many users in System B and I want these messages to be shown whenever the user log into the system. So my problem is, if System B keeps consuming messages even when the users are not logged in how can they see the messages which are already consumed?
Should I store the consumed messages in a database? I don't understand how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is one of message persistence and or re-delivery. There are a couple of approaches:

1. JMS Durable subscription: you could make a durable subscription on a topic from system B and only consume messages while users are logged in. When you don't receive() messages, your messages will be held at the broker for you until you call receive() again. In case A sent messages persistently, all of this is saved by the ActiveMQ broker on disk.
2. JMS Queue: system A puts messages into a queue and System B doesn't pick up the messages unless users are logged in. The queue will get bigger until you call receive() again from system B. Similar to durable subscriptions, but with a queue you can only have one consumer for each message. With durable subscriptions it's a easier to configure a fault-tolerant version of system B...
3. Add a 'replay server' for n-times delivery: system A publishes to a topic (could be non-persistent) and a third component (C) would also subscribe to every message and persist to disk. When system B needs to see a message again, it could ask system C for those messages, ideally supporting from_time, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could let SystemB read all the messages and act as a gateway between JMS and the system itself, i.e. store each user message in the database and when a user logs in, read those messages from the database and display them. If the user has to acknowledge they've read each message that might be a better solution as you can then track if they've read them all and delete each one from the database as they acknowledge they've read it.

Another solution might be [virtual topics and queues](https://tuhrig.de/virtual-topics-in-activemq/). A single topic that messages are sent to that is split into queues, one per user. When a user logs in, SystemB reads from that user's queue. This is separate from the application's domain (it's JMS at this point) so the message is marked as consumed and is taken off the queue by ActiveMQ. If the user doesn't read it and needs to see it the next time they login then you need the database solution.

It's essentially where two domains meet. The information the user needs to see comes in on JMS, which has its own rules (message consumed, remove from queue etc). The information then enters your application's domain which might have different rules (must read, save for next login etc).

If a user doesn't login for a long period of time, their queue might fill up and not be able to receive any more messages, whereas, if the messages are always read and stored in a database it doesn't matter how frequently they login as the database should be better at holding large amounts of messages.

Another option is one [topic](http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html) per user and messages are sent to those topics but other systems would need to know which users are in your system, which probably isn't a good idea. Or you could use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) to route incoming messages on the main topic to user topics. The messages would need to be durable and transacted in case the broker went down. When a user logs in, read from the topic to get all their messages. You can route based on [content](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) or headers.